# How to specify the generic type of a collection?

Tags: java, generics, reflection, collections

I want to define a function which can convert a kind of Set to another, like convert HashSet to LinkedHashSet. Here is the function declaration. The sp is sharedpreferences.

```
public Set<String> decodeStringSet(String key, @Nullable Set<String> defaultValue, Class<? extends Set> cls){
    Set<String> result = sp.getStringSet(key, defaultValue);
    if(result == null){
        return defaultValue;
    }
    else {
        String[] array = result.toArray(new String[0]);
        Set<String> a;
        try {
            a = cls.newInstance();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | InstantiationException var7) {
            return defaultValue;
        }

        a.addAll(Arrays.asList(array));
        return a;
    }
}
```

However, the compiler remind me that "Unchecked assignment: '? extends java.util.Set' to 'java.util.Set<java.lang.String>'" on "a = cls.newInstance();". I don't know how to change cls to cls<java.lang.String>.

Comment: `x = new LinkedHashSet( existingSet )` will create a new set with all the members of the existing set.  I'm having trouble understanding what your code above actually does.

Comment: I mean that I will not specify what the Set is. The specific type of set is passed with a parameter Class<? extends Set> cls, which means I have to create a new set with reflection.

Comment: It would probably be easier and cleaner to pass a `Supplier<Set<String>>`

Answer (score 1):

The warning is unavoidable. Isolate it in a helper method and toss the appropriate `@SuppressWarnings` at it. Or, refactor how this thing works. In general, the generics of `Class<?>` are weird and don't work well; if you try to write code that relies on the generics part to make it work, it's likely to result in many situations where you can't avoid these warnings, and the API is suboptimal.<sup>1</sup>

One tricky way to do what you're trying to do here in a one-size-fits-all way is so-called Super Type Tokens. You can search the web for this concept, because for what you're specifically doing here, STTs are overkill. What you are looking for, is a *supplier*.

You want the caller not to pass you the type of a set. No. You want the caller to pass you a piece of code that, if executed, creates the set.

While we're at it, let's get rid of the array, you're shifting the elements through that array for absolutely no sensible reason.

```
public <S extends Set<String>> S decodeStringSet(String key, @Nullable Set<String> defaultValue, Supplier<S> setMaker) {
    Set<String> result = sp.getStringSet(key, defaultValue);
    if(result == null) return defaultValue;

    S a = setMaker.get();
    a.addAll(result);
    return a;
}
```

This code can be used as follows:

```
LinkedHashSet<String> mySet = decodeStringSet("myKey", null, LinkedHashSet::new);
```

Perhaps you're unfamiliar with this syntax. `new LinkedHashSet()` will, when you run that code, create a LinkedHashSet. In contrast, `LinkedHashSet::new` will, when you run that code, produce an object that can be asked to create a LinkedHashSet, by invoking its `get()` method. One does the act right this very moment. The other wraps 'do the act' into a little machine. You can hand the machine to other code, or press the button on the machine to make it do the act, and you can press the button as often as you feel like.

---

[1] Need some more explanations as to why relying on the generics of `j.l.Class` is awkward and not a good idea?

A class object simply **cannot**, itself, represent generics, whereas generics can represent generics. That is: `List<List<String>>` is perfectly fine. However, `Class<List<String>>` does not make sense. You can write it, (j.l.Class does not have hardcoded rules to keep sanity alive in the langspec), but it doesn't represent anything: There's just one class object that represents the type `j.u.List`. This one object cannot therefore represent the generics; you can't have one class object representing `List<String>` and another representing `List<Integer>`. Less important, but still annoying - there are things class objects can represent that generics cannot. `int.class` is types as `Class<Integer>` but this isn't quite right.

Hence, in your example, the compiler consider `Class<? extends Set>` as problematic; it's got a raw type *inside* the generics. However, it is technically correct, in that it is not possible to represent e.g. a `Set<T>`, merely 'a Set, whose generics are unknown, given that j.l.Class objects cannot represent them'.

Lastly, classes basically only produce (the P in PECS - which explains what the difference is between `<Number>`, `<? extends Number>`, and `<? super Number>`); it is mentally difficult to fathom the difference between `Class<? extends String>` and `Class<String>`, because it's an irrelevant difference, given that j.l.Class only produces. And yet, often you really do need to write `Class<? extends String>` because if you don't, the compiler refuses to compile your code for imaginary, irrelevant reasons. That's because, again, j.l.Class is not hardcoded in the lang spec: The compiler does not *know* that there is no effective distinction between `Class<T>` and `Class<? extends T>`, and java does not have a way to mark off a given generics param as forced Produces-only or some such.